# 500 internal server error .htaccess: </files> without matching <files> section, referer: http://localhost/

Tags: apache

Hi i am  getting following error on my Apache error log file...and 500 internal server error help me to solve this ..

```
[Wed Mar 13 16:33:13 2013] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] C:/wamp/www/phpwork/.htaccess: </files> without matching <files> section, referer: http://localhost/
```

my .htaccess file is

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule (.*\.(png|gif|jpg|jpeg|js|css|swf))$ webroot/img_handler.php?arg=$1 [L] 
   RewriteRule    ^$ webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

# disable directory browsing -IMPORTANT, do NOT remove.
Options -Indexes

# protect the htaccess file
<files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

# disable the server signature
ServerSignature Off


# protect php.ini
#<files *.ini>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

Comment: can you please give content of htaccess file.it will be helpful

Comment: file code is updated..

Answer (score 0):

```
# protect php.ini
#<files *.ini>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

here you commented "files" directive

plese remove comment to do your files section same to this :

```
<files *.ini>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```