# Experiencing a server error whilst working with xampp

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, xampp

I have set up a local wordpress install with xampp. 
I have been able to get going with my website build as normal and update, edit content.

I was in the middle of doing this just a whilst ago when I experienced problems uploading an image. Now when I try to access localhost/mysite I am getting a server error.

[image]

I have no idea why this should be as I have made no changes to the .htaccess file or any of the files in the wordpress install.

I have had a look in the error log and this is the result...

> [Thu Nov 29 10:14:11.126012 2018] [core:alert] [pid 12060:tid 1948] [client ::1:50434] C:/xampp/htdocs/mascar/.htaccess:  without matching  section, referer: http://localhost/mascar/wp-admin/post.php?post=18&action=elementor
>   [Thu Nov 29 10:14:17.058257 2018] [core:alert] [pid 12060:tid 1948] [client ::1:50443] C:/xampp/htdocs/mascar/.htaccess:  without matching  section, referer: http://localhost/mascar/wp-admin/post.php?post=18&action=elementor
>   [Thu Nov 29 10:14:24.869216 2018] [core:alert] [pid 12060:tid 1948] [client ::1:50452] C:/xampp/htdocs/mascar/.htaccess:  without matching  section, referer: http://localhost/mascar/wp-admin/post.php?post=18&action=elementor
>   [Thu Nov 29 10:14:26.096279 2018] [core:alert] [pid 12060:tid 1948] [client ::1:50455] C:/xampp/htdocs/mascar/.htaccess:  without matching  section, referer: http://localhost/mascar/wp-admin/post.php?post=18&action=elementor
>   [Thu Nov 29 10:14:35.026682 2018] [core:alert] [pid 12060:tid 1948] [client ::1:50470] C:/xampp/htdocs/mascar/.htaccess:  without matching  section, referer: http://localhost/mascar/wp-admin/post.php?post=18&action=elementor
>   [Thu Nov 29 10:14:41.097039 2018] [core:alert] [pid 12060:tid 1948] [client ::1:50479] C:/xampp/htdocs/mascar/.htaccess:  without matching  section, referer: http://localhost/mascar/wp-admin/post.php?post=18&action=elementor
>   [Thu Nov 29 10:14:50.536319 2018] [core:alert] [pid 12060:tid 1948] [client ::1:50494] C:/xampp/htdocs/mascar/.htaccess:  without matching  section, referer: http://localhost/mascar/wp-admin/post.php?post=18&action=elementor
>   [Thu Nov 29 10:14:54.729081 2018] [core:alert] [pid 12060:tid 1948] [client ::1:50499] C:/xampp/htdocs/mascar/.htaccess:  without matching  section, referer: http://localhost/mascar/wp-admin/post.php?post=18&action=elementor
>   [Thu Nov 29 10:15:20.275422 2018] [core:alert] [pid 12060:tid 1940] [client ::1:50537] C:/xampp/htdocs/mascar/.htaccess:  without matching  section
>   [Thu Nov 29 10:15:46.718139 2018] [core:alert] [pid 12060:tid 1932] [client ::1:50584] C:/xampp/htdocs/mascar/.htaccess:  without matching  section
>   [Thu Nov 29 10:18:50.626839 2018] [core:alert] [pid 12060:tid 1940] [client ::1:50855] C:/xampp/htdocs/mascar/.htaccess:  without matching  section
>   [Thu Nov 29 10:20:02.653258 2018] [core:alert] [pid 12060:tid 1932] [client ::1:50969] C:/xampp/htdocs/mascar/.htaccess:  without matching  section
>   [Thu Nov 29 10:20:40.383046 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 9384:tid 696] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>   [Thu Nov 29 10:20:40.596605 2018] [core:warn] [pid 9384:tid 696] AH00098: pid file C:/xampp/apache/logs/httpd.pid overwritten -- Unclean shutdown of previous Apache run?
>   [Thu Nov 29 10:20:40.600605 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 9384:tid 696] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>   [Thu Nov 29 10:20:43.371954 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9384:tid 696] AH00455: Apache/2.4.37 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.1.1 PHP/7.2.12 configured -- resuming normal operations
>   [Thu Nov 29 10:20:43.371954 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9384:tid 696] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC15 Server built: Oct 18 2018 17:16:04
>   [Thu Nov 29 10:20:43.371954 2018] [core:notice] [pid 9384:tid 696] AH00094: Command line: 'c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
>   [Thu Nov 29 10:20:43.371954 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 9384:tid 696] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 16156
>   [Thu Nov 29 10:20:44.996186 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 16156:tid 644] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>   [Thu Nov 29 10:20:45.166669 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 16156:tid 644] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
>   [Thu Nov 29 10:20:45.242858 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 16156:tid 644] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
>   [Thu Nov 29 10:21:03.326342 2018] [core:alert] [pid 16156:tid 1924] [client ::1:51070] C:/xampp/htdocs/mascar/.htaccess:  without matching  section
>   [Thu Nov 29 10:21:09.229976 2018] [core:alert] [pid 16156:tid 1916] [client ::1:51071] C:/xampp/htdocs/mascar/.htaccess:  without matching  section
>   [Thu Nov 29 10:21:32.086335 2018] [core:alert] [pid 16156:tid 1884] [client ::1:51127] C:/xampp/htdocs/mascar/.htaccess:  without matching  section

There is nothing in here that leaps out at me as an obvious cause of the error.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT: 
This is my .htaccess file.

I did add a short command but then changed it back to exactly as it was before.

This is all it consists of.

```
#BEGIN WordPress<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /mascar/ RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] RewriteCond
 %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /mascar/index.php [L] </IfModule>
  #END WordPress
```

Comment: `.htaccess: without matching section` looks really bad. You made some changes to `.htaccess` probably, and now you have a broken `.htaccess` file. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15383578/500-internal-server-error-htaccess-files-without-matching-files-section) and [This](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) may provide the answer

Comment: Please don't post in comments. Edit and add it to your question instead.

Comment: I have edited this now

Comment: @Chris, The first line is the cause. Everything on it is commented. Check the links in my first comment, also check [This](https://www.askapache.com/htaccess/) out. you will see what i mean.

Comment: Thank you @EugeneAnisiutkin ! I used this [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess) by just replacing the Basic WP code and now it works again! I still have no idea what happened there